# Keras "trainable" scope

Tags: python, keras

I have two Keras networks. Let's say for the sake of explanation that my model is similar to GAN. So, we have a Discriminator(D) and a Generator(G).
Obviously, in order to train the (G), the (D) layers should be frozen.
If, I freeze them using `D.trainable = False` then should I invert this parameter when to train the (D)?

What is the scope of `model.trainable` in Keras?
I have seen codes that only change this argument status once:
https://github.com/nairouz/Keras-GAN/blob/master/gan/gan.py

How is it possible to do so? Any explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How can I "freeze" Keras layers?](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-freeze-keras-layers):

> Additionally, you can set the trainable property of a layer to `True` or `False` after instantiation. For this to take effect, you will need to call `compile()` on your model after modifying the trainable property.

And the same applies to models. This means that when you set `D.trainable = False`, this doesn't take effect until you compile `D` (or any other model leveraging `D`), so it doesn't affect models that you have previously compiled.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the  clarification!